# Click each ID in array

Tags: javascript, php

I need to be able to go through each item in the array and click it. The array represents ID's of elements that need to be clicked.
Here is the code that retrieves the array and places it in the variable arrayResponse

> //["2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","5"]

```
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); //New request object
oReq.onload = function() {

//The actual data is found on this.responseText
  var arrayResponse = this.responseText; //Assign array to variable
  alert(arrayResponse);

  arrayResponse.forEach(function(entry) {
  //Click through array here
});
};
oReq.open("get", "load.php", true);
oReq.send();
```

HTML

```
 <img id="1" class="image" src="ON-Green.png">
```

Comment: is there a selector in HTML with this ids? an array having the same multiple elements

Comment: They are just images with IDs, when i user clicks an image something happens. I want each ID in the array to be clicked through Javascript to return the results on the index page

Comment: "I need to" is not a question.  What exactly are you asking here.

Comment: How to add a Javascript function that will click each ID in the array

Comment: @Luke check mine

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo just tried that, didnt work

Comment: share the html where you have images

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo added, all ID's are structured the same way

Comment: where is that id referenced in your html? you must be having ` <img id="1" …`. no?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the images have entry as ID.

```
arrayResponse.forEach(function(entry) {
document.getElementById(entry).click(); //using js
$("#"+entry).click(); //using jquery
});
```

Comment: A pure JavaScript solution here would be better

Answer (score 0):

you already have a foreach loop for get every separate, you  need a click to each ID,
follow my example:

```
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); //New request object
oReq.onload = function() {

//The actual data is found on this.responseText
var arrayResponse = this.responseText; //Assign array to variable
alert(arrayResponse);

arrayResponse.forEach(function(entry) {
      document.querySelector('#'+entry).click();
});
};
oReq.open("get", "load.php", true);
oReq.send();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.
A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.